# R "Error in density.default(raw) : argument 'x' must be numeric" in data.frame with all int values

Tags: r, dataframe, types

Why am I getting this error when all of my types seem to be numeric?

```
> str(raw)
'data.frame':   404166147 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ piece_1_A  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ piece_1_B  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ piece_2_A : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ piece_2_B : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ item_1_A : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ item_1_B : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ piece_2_A: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ piece_2_B: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
> sapply(raw, typeof)
  item_1_A   item_1_B  item_2_A  item_2_B  piece_1_A  piece_1_B piece_2_A
   "integer"    "integer"    "integer"    "integer"    "integer"    "integer"    "integer" 
piece_2_B 
   "integer" 
> density(raw[,1])
Error in density.default(raw[, 1]) : argument 'x' must be numeric
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking the class of the variable. The first column could be factor or character and the `typeof` would still return integer. You need to convert the variable to class numeric.

To see behavior of `typeof` and `class` try the example below:

```
# load sample dataset
data(mtcars)
# check class and type of all variables
sapply(mtcars, class)
sapply(mtcars, typeof)
# convert gear variable to class factor
mtcars$gear <- as.factor(mtcars$gear)
# check class and type again
sapply(mtcars, class)
sapply(mtcars, typeof)
```